# Attempt to create a macro in excel that controls the out put of a cell based on the value of other cells in the row

Tags: excel, vba

[Example of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IONJr.jpg)
I have been trying to learn VBA to write a code to create a macro to help me get an output cell depending on many conditions in other cells.
So what I want is to fill each cell in column M based on other parameters in the same row of that cell depending on different level of priority:

1- if the cell in Column J is not "PASS" then I want the corresponding cell in M column to show whatever is in J other than "PASS".

2- if the cell in column J is "PASS" then the corresponding cell in column M will depend whether the cell in column I is "NO ANOMALY DETECTED" or anything else. If it's anything else then make the cell in column M whatever is in column I. Otherwise if it is "NO ANOMALY DETECTED" then make the value of the cell in column M similar to that in column G but replacing "NO ANOMALY DETECTED - " by "Euploid, " and keep XY or XX.

I also tried colouring based on value.:
The code I used:

```
Sub QC()
If Range("J2:J98").Value <> PASS Then Range("M2:M98").Value = Range("J2:J98")
End If

Sub Abnormality()
If Range("J2:J98").Value = PASS and Range("I2:I98").Value <> "NO ANOMALY DETECTED" Then Range("M2:M98").Value = Range("I2:I98") and cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
End If


Sub Euploid_Sex()
If Range("J2:J98").Value = PASS and Range("I2:I98").Value = "NO ANOMALY DETECTED" and Range("G2:G98").Value = "NO ANOMALY DETECTED - XY" Then Range("M2:M98").Value = "Euploid, XY"
ElseIf Range("J2:J98").Value = PASS and Range("I2:I98").Value = "NO ANOMALY DETECTED" and Range("G2:G98").Value = "NO ANOMALY DETECTED - XX" Then Range("M2:M98").Value = "Euploid, XX"
End IF

Sub Result_Coulour()
IF Range("M2:M98").Value = "Euploid, XY" then Range ("M2:M98").Font.Color - RGB(0, 176, 240)
ElseIf Range("M2:M98").Value = "Euploid, XX" then Range ("M2:M98").Font.Color - RGB(255, 153, 255)
End IF
```

Comment: You can do this with formulas and conditional formatting btw... is VBA a necessity?

Comment: Macro would be better as you can just apply it on any new file, but would it be possible with formulas ?

Answer (score 1):

This would really be done best in formulae in the sheet itself. Otherwise, you can't really assess each value in a range in VBA without looping through the range itself e.g.

```
Sub QC()
If Range("J2:J98").Value <> PASS Then Range("M2:M98").Value = Range("J2:J98")
End If
```

Should be something more like:

```
Sub QC()
For Each cel In Range("J2:J98")
   If cel.Value <> "PASS" Then cel.Offset(0, 3).Value = cel.Value
Next cel
End If
```

I'm going through each `cel` in the range, and if the value is not equal to "PASS" then I'm telling it the cell 3 columns to the right (`Offset(0,3)`) should be the same `cel.Value`

You could then nest your logics e.g.

```
Sub QC()
For Each cel In Range("J2:J98")
   If cel.Value <> "PASS" Then
       If cel.Offset(0,1).Value <> "NO ANOMALY DETECTED" Then
           cel.Offset(0, 3).Value = cel.Offset(0,1).Value
       Else
           cel.Offset(0,3).Value = cel.Value
       End If
   End If
Next cel
End If
```

---

However, there are some cool things you can do in VBA like filling a range with formulae to do calculations and then replacing it instantly with those calculated numbers (to avoid having formulae in the cells), so you could do something like:

```
Sub FillColumnM()
  Range("K2:K98").Formula = "=IF(J2<>""PASS"",J2,IF(I2<>""NO ANOMALY DETECTED"",I2))"
  Range("K2:K98").Value2 = Range("K2:K98").Value2
End Sub
```

Comment: Ha, that was a typo, the line had auto-fed to the next line because it was too long so I didn't even realise! Corrected now.

Comment: I tried it , it didn't work day next without FOR. Also seems to have a problem using the same Sub name many times